# 2.1 downmix with libfdk_aac using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I have several input media files I'd like to process. The input audio stream of each file is encoded in ac-3 with a 5.1 channel layout (back or side) at 384kbps.

The objective is for the target media file to contain a downmixed audio stream converted to 2.1 channel layout (at 192kbps) in aac format!

I use ffmpeg for the entire process and I can achieve the objective using the following parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -vn -c:a aac -b:a 192k -filter_complex "pan=2.1|FL<c0+c2+c4|FR<c1+c2+c5|LFE=c2" outfile.m4a
```

The resulting audio file has the following properties:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 2.1, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
```

However(!) if I use `libfdk_aac` instead, I end up with a stereo file and the LFE channel being dropped:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s (default)
```

**How do I encode the audio stream using libfdk_aac without dropping the LFE channel?**

The result is the same when using automatic channel mapping. The following command produces a 2.1 audio stream when using `aac` instead of `libfdk_aac` as audio codec option:

```
ffmpeg -y -i infile.mp4 -vn -c:a aac -b:a 192k -af pan=2.1 test.m4a
```

For the sake of this questions I neglect all properties of the source video material as I am convinced it is not important to the answer of the question.

Comment: In this post, I don't see 2.1 as listed format supported by `libfdk_aac`: https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libfdk_aac doesn't support the 2.1 channel layout:

```
$ ffmpeg -h encoder=libfdk_aac
[...]
Encoder libfdk_aac [Fraunhofer FDK AAC]:
    Supported channel layouts: mono stereo 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.1 7.1(wide) 7.1
```

You'll have to use a supported layout or use a different encoder instead, such as `-c:a aac` as you mentioned.